# How to skip a particular test in parametrized test functions in pytest

Tags: pytest, skip, parameterized-tests, pytest-markers

I have a pytest function that has markers @pytest.mark.win_11 and @pytest.mark.parametrize('os,result',[('win_11','result1'),('win_8','result2')])

When I run test as 'pytest -m win_11', it is running the tests for both set of parameters. I want to run the test only when the os version is win_11.

So, can we combine both marker and parametrize option for single test?
Is there a way to skip test with os = win_8 when test is run as 'pytest -m win_11' ?

The code looks as follows:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.win_11
@pytest.mark.parametrize('os_version,result',[('win_11','result1'),('win_8','result2')])
def test_set1_1(os_version, expected_result):
    # some code
```

Comment: This seems `os_version` would be better served as a fixture.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to assign the marker dynamically through `@pytest.mark.parametrize`

```
def parametrize():
    for version, result in [('win_11', 'result1'), ('win_8', 'result2')]:
        marks = []
        if version == 'win_11':
            marks.append(pytest.mark.win_11)
        else:
            marks.append(pytest.mark.win_8)
        yield pytest.param(version, result, marks=marks)


@pytest.mark.parametrize('os_version, result', parametrize())
def test_set1_1(os_version, result):
    print(os_version, result)
```

Without marker `pytest`

```
============================= test session starts =============================
collecting ... collected 2 items

example.py::test_set1_1[win_11-result1] PASSED                           [ 50%]
win_11 result1

example.py::test_set1_1[win_8-result2] PASSED                            [100%]
win_8 result2
```

With `pytest -m win_11`

```
============================= test session starts =============================
collecting ... collected 2 items / 1 deselected / 1 selected

example.py::test_set1_1[win_11-result1] PASSED                           [100%]
win_11 result1
```